# How to add Facebook Pixel on custom pages of wordpress website without Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages, facebook-pixel

I want to use PixelYourSite Plugin for my wordpress website. But its not working for for the custom pages that I built. is there any other way to make it work. Or is there anything I am missing? Can you help and suggest what should I do? I have not tried any other Plugin yet. But if this one's not working, I don't think any other plugin would work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert pixel code directly. Try find the wordpress theme editor on Wordpress Painel > appearance > Editor... And try find the files that contain the head tag to past and update the code. Try read the facebook documentation too on https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755?id=1205376682832142